# in jsf, how to show please wait message or progress bar while file download?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

In JSF, is there any way to show "please wait message" when the download start, and have to hide it once the download complete(or save file window appear).

i am using following jsf code to download a file.

```
<h:commandButton id="getDownload" value="download"  action="#{bean.downloadAction()}"   >
```

Note : I am using plain jsf, not using any component frameworks like primeface/ Richfaces

Comment: How are you downloading the file? can you give us a glimpse of your downloadAction?

Comment: As I understand it there is no easy way, since it's a full request so no complete event to hook up to. Primefaces have solved it with the js function monitorDownload. I believe they add a cookie to the response and continously look for that cookie. You could check how they have done it. http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1616

Comment: Or here: http://gruffcode.com/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser/